# Can I pass a variable through a function to increase its global value? [python]

Tags: python, function, global-variables

Hello I am creating a novice python game as practice and I have written this function that checks a variable (e.g. your strength level) and gives you a % chance to pass and increase the global variable.

```
import random
strength = 0
intelligence = 0
cunning = 0

def statCheck(x):
    global strength
    global intelligence
    global cunning
    
    winChance = random.randint(1,4) + x
    if winChance >= 1:
        x = x + 1
        print(f"You have passed and gain one stat is it {x}")
        return x
    else:
        print("You have failed")
```

I was expecting to pass strength/intelligence/cunning through it and have them increase for each time they pass the %chance but the value only increases the value of x.

```
import functions

strength = 0
intelligence = 0
cunning = 0

functions.statCheck(strength)
print(f"You have {strength} strength")
```

This gives me "You have passed and gain one stat is it 1" but also
"You have 0 strength" How do I use a function to increase a variable in this way?

Comment: You cannot set a variable by passing it into a function. The function only receives the *value*, not the variable.

Comment: I see thank you I must be barking up the wrong tree and take it from a different angle